# How to inject a MockModule into DaggerAppComponent?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, daggermock

I have been using Dagger Android for a while, and now I want to inject a MockModule for testing purposes, and I do not know how to get it. I have seen on some posts that they call something like:

```
DaggerAppComponent.builder()
  .dataModule(myMockModule)
  .create(this).inject(this)
```

But I have this configuration:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivitiesBuilderModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    DataModule::class
])
internal interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<CbvApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<CbvApplication>()

}
```

and when I create the application, the `DaggerAppComponent.Builder` does not provides the `setters` for the individual modules. That is nice cause in the app code I do not have to worry about it, but on testing, I want to inject my mock objects through mockComponents / modules.

Anyone can point me in the right direction???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, I am not sure we can mock the whole module all together, but we can **mock dependencies** provided by **module**. 
I have achieved this like, I need to mock **DataModule** for UI Testing so I have created this `TestDataModule` and provided mocks for the dependency.

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
class TestDataModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesDataRepository(): DataRepository {
        return mock()
    }
}
```

Here is `TestApplicationModule`

```
@Module
abstract class TestApplicationModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindContext(application: Application): Context
}
```

And created `TestApplicationComponent` which will take the required modules

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    (AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class),
    (TestApplicationModule::class),
    (UIModule::class),
    (PresentationModule::class),
    (TestDataModule::class)])
interface TestApplicationComponent {

    // Here you can add additional direct mock 
    // classes to access them directly from component reference
    fun dataRepository(): DataRepository 


    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): TestApplicationComponent.Builder

        fun build(): TestApplicationComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: TestAppplication)
}
```

I had to test UI using Android JUnit Test runner and espresso, So I used UIModule and Presentation Module as it is (Cannot mock as wanted to test). So have to mock other dependencies which are not part of that UI Unit tests like **DataRepository**

You can add other modules like CacheModule and RemoteModules as mocks as they don't play any role in UI Unit testing.

**Finally**, Create `DaggerTestApplicationComponent` in `TestApplication` like this,

```
class TestApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>
    private lateinit var appComponent: TestApplicationComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = DaggerTestApplicationComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
        appComponent.inject(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = activityInjector
}
```

So now DaggerTestApplicationComponent will generate required dependency graph.

**Note**: It is required to stub all the methods called on mocked dependencies